# How to skip a 'Partial<Interface>' property based on a ternary operation result

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript interface that I am using to create an object of. In my case, I am only *partially* implementing the interface since not all the property are always available.

One of the property I want to populate is based on whether I have a certain value or not from a MongoDB query.

```
const Person {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

...

const newPerson : Partial<Person> = {
  name: result.name,
  age: result.age ? result.age : // skip property
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread operator here:

```
const newPerson: Partial<Person> = {
  name: result.name,
  ...(result.age && { age: result.age })
}
```